# Using Amazon AWS SDK instead of Paperclip for active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, activeadmin

I am developing an admin panel for a legacy database which has images stored on S3. The way this is done is a full url pointing out to the resource on S3 which is publicly readable.

Paperclip store this in different fields in a database. I need to do these steps.

- Upload the file to my server
- Generate a UUID
- Upload file to S3 with correct permissions and name it with the UUID.
- Save the complete url in a single db col.

My only requirement is uploading single image file and storing it in a single field as explained. Dont care which lib I use.

My questions are

- Can I configure paperclip to change its default behaviour to do this?
- If I use AWS sdk myself do I have to use somekind of threads? I cant see a decent example from where we can use Model to upload image in the same way as done in paperclip.
- How is the image recieved in model when uploading using paperclip and active admin.

These may be basic questions but I am a ROR newbie! Guidance and help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using paperclip I used [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and fog. Which gives the ability to override name and storage location etc.

```
storage :fog
def initialize(*)
 super
  self.fog_directory    = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
end

def store_dir
  'pronunciations'
end
def cache_dir
  "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads/pronunciations"
end

def extension_white_list
  %w(mp3 m4a)
end
```